# Can you keep a div always visiable at top while scrolling through css?

Tags: css

Can you keep a div always visiable at top while scrolling through css only (not jquery)?

Comment: [**Study**](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have one example :

```
nav {
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
left:0;
height:50px
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can by utilizing the 'position: fixed' property.